# Помогите с системой спавна машин

Tags: lua, roblox

Я написал такой простой код:

```lua
local open = false
local menu = script.Parent.menu

function test()
    if open == false then
        menu.Visible = true
        open = true
        clone = game.workspace.Part12
        local test = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
        pos = test.Character.Head.Position
        clone.Position = Vector3.new(pos)
    else
        menu.Visible = false
        open = false
    end
end

script.Parent.spawnbutton.MouseButton1Down:Connect(test)
```

Он должен показывать меню и телепортировать парт12 из воркспэйса в позицию головы игрока. Я много изменял код где он выводил позицию головы, и там все нормально но... При телепортировании он телепортирует парт даже не близко к голове. Можете пожалуйста подсказать как исправить код, и желательно сделать чтобы парт телепортировался не прям в голову а рядом с игроком. Скрипт не локальный, обычный, все что надо есть в startergui, парт в вокрспэйс.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)